# No me reconoce un bucle tras un array en netbeans

Tags: java, array, netbeans, bucle-for

tengo un problema, en un proyecto normal y corriente sin importar nada, estoy haciendo un array muy simple y después de introducirlo, añado un bucle for, y el programa no me lo reconoce y no se como arreglarlo, si es que tengo que importar alguna función o algo.

Me dice el programa que introduzca ';' en el bucle o que es una expresión ilegal.
Gracias.

```
public class PrimerosArrays {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        
        int [] num = new int [12];
        
        num[0] = 39;
        num[1] = -2;
        num[4] = 0;
        num[6] = 14;
        num[8] = 5;
        num[9] = 120;
        
        for (int i = 0, i < 12, i++){
            System.out.println(num[i]);
        }
        
        
        
    }
```

Comment: Copia y pega el error completo para saber cual es.

Comment: @Antonio bienvenido a Stack overflow en español.Es muy importante que revises las recomendaciones de [¿como elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Por favor incluye el detalle del error como indica Excorpion. A simple vista parece que te falta cerrar el `}` de la clase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola antonio fijate que tu bucle, tiene separadas las condiciones con comas cuando deberias separarlo con punto y coma como aparece en el código que te he puesto.
debes separarlo con punto y coma de la siguiente manera:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {

   system.out.println(num[i]);
    
 }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Javier :)